# Ring request map deconstruction macro

Tags: clojure, macros, compojure, ring

Trying to make a macro deconstruct parameters from a ring request map using a Macro. It works ok:

```
(defmacro defpage [fname args & body]
  `(defn ~fname [{{:keys ~args} :params}]
     ~@body))

(defpage h-projects [name description]
  ; some code using name and description...
   )

(defroutes app-routes
   (ANY "/p/" [] h-projects)
```

But, I would like to be able to use the request map directly in the h-projects function:

```
(defpage h-projects [name description]
  ; some code using name and description, and also
  ; the request map.
   )
```

How can the defpage macro be modified to make the request map available to the h-projects function?

I know I could change the parameters for the h-projects function, but I would like to keep the simple vector with parameters, not som deep nested deconstructing map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can destructure with the `:as` keyword to get a handle on the entire destructured map.](http://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#_map_binding_destructuring) To do this in a macro I'd recommend you take an input for what the name should be:

```
(defmacro defpage [fname args map-name & body]
  `(defn ~fname [{{:keys ~args :as ~map-name} :params}]
     ~@body))
```

but you can also choose to just define a "magic name" that all `defpage`s share. This kinda loses clarity because when you read a `defpage` it looks like a name comes out of nowhere.

```
(defmacro defpage [fname args & body]
  `(defn ~fname [{{:keys ~args :as ~'my-magic-name} :params}]
     ~@body))
```

The ~' allows for namespace capture.

Comment: Your answer seems to partially work. The non-magic macro works, but the macro with my-magic-name introduces the following error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't let qualified name: my-magic-name, compiling